# How to set the value of the constant equal to the value of fixed step automatically?

Tags: matlab, simulink

there is the model which does calculations based on the value of the Fixed-step size. Is it possible to set the constant's block value equal to the value of the fixed-step automatically?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to create a MATLAB variable with the given value, and use that variable in both the `Constant Block` and for all sample times that require it (including specifying a fixed step size on the Solvers page).